# mvc EditorTemplate DisplayMod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a mobile website using MVC-4.

Integer fields should be entered from the numeric keyboard, I use the EditorTemplate `number` wich creates an HTML element like this:

```
<input ... type="number" value="45" />
```

My customer doesn’t much appreciate the numeric keyboard shown this way on his iPhone and has asked me to show the phone keyboard which is shown by using `type="tel"` instead of `type="number"`.

I’m struggling as to how to accomplish this in my EditorTemplate `number.cshtml`.

I’ve created a separate iPhone DisplayMode but am not sure how to use it combined with an EditorTemplate, I’ve tried copying it to `number.iPhone.cshtml` but EditorTemplates don’t seem to work that way…

Is there some method to retrieve the current DisplayMode so I can solve this problem ?

```
// pseudo code I guess …

@if(DisplayMode == "iPhone")    
{ 
   @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line", type = "tel" })   
}    
else     
{
   @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line", type = "number" })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried copying it to number.iPhone.cshtml but EditorTemplates don’t seem to work that way...

No, editor templates works exactly the same way as all other views. So assuming that you have registered a display mode called `iPhone` (because out of the box there's no such Display Mode):

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
    ContextCondition = context => context.Request.UserAgent.... some condition on the User Agent
});
```

and assuming you have the following model that gets passed to your view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType("Number")]
    public decimal Foo { get; set; }
}
```

in which you render an editor template for the Foo property as usual:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

Then assuming that you hit your website with an User-Agent that matches the condition you wrote when you registered your `iPhone` display mode, the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Number.iPhone.cshtml` will be rendered.

Comment: I had been testing this with an 'int' in my Model expecting the 'Number.cshtml' to be used, as it turns out it uses 'Int32.cshtml' for an 'int' (offcourse). So it is working great now.

Thanks !